# Design pattern using interface or abstract

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I am trying to calculate the print cost base on different paper size, single side or double side. So here is the detail:

Also need to support for other paper sizes will be added in the future.

And according to my design, developer can just create a A5 class for example to support other paper size, and add other condition in the factory class.

Could someone review my code and help me on whether I have to use interface instead of abstract class?

Here is my code:

PageBase:

```
public abstract class PageBase {
    abstract double GetCost(int total, int color, boolean isSingleSide);
    abstract void CalculateUnitPrice(boolean isSingleSide);
}
```

A4Page Class:

```
public class A4Page extends PageBase {
    public double blackAndWhitePrintUnitCost;
    public double colorPrintUniCost;

    @Override
    public double GetCost(int total, int color, boolean isSingleSide) {
        CalculateUnitPrice(isSingleSide);
        return color* colorPrintUniCost + (total-color)* blackAndWhitePrintUnitCost;
    }

    @Override
    public void CalculateUnitPrice(boolean isSingleSide) {
        if (isSingleSide) {
            this.blackAndWhitePrintUnitCost = 0.15;
            this.colorPrintUniCost = 0.25;
        }
        else {
            this.blackAndWhitePrintUnitCost = 0.10;
            this.colorPrintUniCost = 0.20;
        }
    }
}
```

PageFactory:

```
public class PageFactory {

    public PageBase GetPage(String pageType) {
        switch (pageType.toUpperCase()) {
            case "A4":
                return new A4Page();
            default:
                return new A4Page();
        }
    }
}
```

Main:

```
public class Main {
    public static void Main() {
        //read
        PageFactory pageFactory = new PageFactory();
        PageBase page = pageFactory.GetPage("A4");
        page.GetCost(0,0,false);
    }
}
```

Comment: A better place for this would be https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @BrandonMcKenzie probably there they will mark the question with negative and someone will vote to close because "is not code from real world".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on CodeReview.se.com (it's not one of the choices to migrate to).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was cross posted.

Answer (score 1):

Decorator is way more elegant than Factory to your problem.

For Decorator, you will need some classes and interfaces:

- Interfaces: Colored, Side and Page. All interfaces has a method `cost()` to be implemented.
- Classes: SingleSide, DoubleSide, ColorPage, BlankAndWhitePage, A4

Usage:

```
Page page1 = new A4(new SingleSide(new ColorPage()))
Page page2 = new A4(new DoubleSide(new BlankAndWhitePage()))

page1.cost();
```

You need to add some value to each component, to be summed and give the expected value. Each object has a "cost".

Some internals:

```
class A4 implements Page {
    //constructor
    private Side side;

    public BigDecimal cost() {
        return this.valueA4 + side.cost();
    }
}

class SingleSide implements Side {
    //constructor
    private Colored colored;

    public BigDecimal cost() {
        return this.valueSingleSided+ colored.cost();
    }
}
```

Something in this line could give you some insights about the best object organization.

Comment: Thanks Dherik, I think of that, but I thought page itself does not have cost, so I tried the factory pattern

Comment: You can remove `cost` from the page if you want. But I think that it could have a price, because each page (A4, A1, etc) has different prices. But see my answer as a guide to resolve your real problem